# Would it make a difference to PHPdoc if I close my tags with colon (example)?

Tags: php, phpdoc, phpdocumentor2

I always use colons in my phpdoc blocs. For example, instead of:

```
/** Some comment
 *
 *@private
 * 
 *@param string $sTable The name of the table 
 *@return bool True otherwise void
 *@example className->tableExists($sTable);
 *@since date
 */
```

Instead of the above, I use the following style:

```
/** Some comment
 *
 * @private
 * 
 * @param   : string $sTable The name of the table 
 * @return  : bool True otherwise void
 * @example : className->tableExists($sTable);
 * @since   : date
 */
```

You see, I prefer to divide the tags and description with colons. It's easier to read and has more style. But I wonder if this makes any difference for PHPdoc parsing the docbloc at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To PHPDocumentor it makes quite a difference. Testing shows the following

```
/**
 * Test constructor.
 * @param : string $var testvar
 *
 */
```

gets documented to:
[image]

Where

```
/**
 * Test constructor.
 * @param  string $var testvar
 *
 */
```

outputs [image]

It is ofcourse somewhat logical that it is that way, as it is a syntax error. If you want to make the docblock look nice, you can align the values with spaces.

```
/** Some comment
 *
 *@private
 *
 *@param   string $sTable The name of the table
 *@return  bool|void      True otherwise void
 *@example className->tableExists($sTable);
 *@since   date
 */
```

Comment: Docblock tags are presumed to use spaces for such visual formatting, so there is likely no document-generator program out there that could handle a colon like this.  PhpDocumentor certainly does not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about PHPDoc itself, but it would make a difference to some IDEs. I tried this in PHPStorm and while `@param` and `@var` were unaffected, `@return` failed out.

[image]

I would be cautious using a non-standard format.